# how to get the value of a variable outside of the onClickListener method

Tags: java, android, scope, onclicklistener, buttonclick

Is there a way to get and use the value of *count* ,(which registers the number of times the user clicks the button) **outside** OnClickListener, that will be used in an equation outisde onClickListener?

I created a method in order to do it but it does work. By putting my value of count in a TextField, I saw that The value of *count* outside OnClick... seems to be always 1 no matter how many times I click on the button.

```
int count=0;
button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                counter();
                text2.setText("count= "+counter());

            }
        }); 
                       text.setText("count= "+counter());
                      ///equation with counter() in it

        private int counter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    count++; 
    return count;
}
}


    }
```

Comment: How do you *know* what the value is? Where are you using it? You call a function with a return value but don't seem to use or display it anywhere...

Comment: The method and how you're calling should work fine. I'm guessing your logging mechanism, which you haven't included here, is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The outside function doesn't work because it is not present within `onClick()`
"The outside function doesn't get called even if you click n times because it is not present in `onclick()` ". `onclick()` method gets invoked when button is clicked.

So outside `counter()` will be called only once so `count=1`.